# Bot sending a message in certain channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to have a command which is similar to "say" command but it's only restricted to bot owner and only sent in one channel at a specific server. Any tips?
Here's my code (not working atm):

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
   if(command === "+ubersay") {
    if(message.author.id !== process.env.ownerID) return;
    const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
    message.delete().catch(O_o=>{}); 
    client.channels.get(process.env.specifiedChannel).send(sayMessage);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should work flawlessly, the only thing that could be a problem is your `const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);` combined with `if(command === "+ubersay") {` Because this askes for your Command to be used in the format `[prefix]+ubersay` so if your prefix is + you would need to do `++ubersay`

Comment: @MOON if that solved your problem, could you please accept this answer by clicking the tick on the left? This will mark your question as resolved ;)